# ReactJS : Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use the 'useHistory' (from react-router-dom) push method on a function that is called by onClick method. The redirect work fine although i get an error in the console that states:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.

**My routing is handled in My App.js as follows:**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Container style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <Router>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div className="tabs">
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                <Route path='/staff' component={InsertingStaff} />
                <Route path='/students' component={InsertingStudents} />
                <Route path='/groups' component={ManageGroups} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Router>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

**and the component that pushes to the router after onClick event:**

```
function GroupsTree() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick(group_item) {
    localStorage.setItem('selected_group', JSON.stringify(group_item))
    history.push("/groups");
  }

  const styles = {
    lines: {
      color: '#0064FF',
      height: '40px'
    },
    node: {
      backgroundColor: '#0064FF',
      border: '1px solid #1890ff',
    },
    text: {
      color: '#FFFFFF',
    }
  };
  const StyledTree = withStyles(styles)(Tree);
  return (
    <TransformWrapper doubleClick={{ disabled: true }} options={{ limitToBounds: false, minScale: 0.6 }} defaultScale={1}>
      <TransformComponent>
        <StyledTree data={data} direction={true} onClick={item => {
          handleClick(item);
        }}></StyledTree>
      </TransformComponent>
    </TransformWrapper>
  )

}
```

any idea on what is causing the error/warning?

Comment: You probably have an asynchronous operation in process before and after the route transition. BTW, where is `Tree` coming from?

Comment: it's an npm component i installed named 'react-vertical-tree'

Comment: Does `TransformComponent` is doing any animations, is this also a third party?

Comment: yes' it is also a 3rd party component that allows me to zoom in and out the tree component and move it around with the mouse etc'

Comment: the animation it does simply react to the users mouse movements

Comment: Well, my guess is that its not cleaning up on unmount or something similar. I would check [this issue](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/issues/30) and maybe you just need to get the latest version of the library. To be sure its `react-zoom-pan-pinch` "fault" i would try running the app without it and see if i get the same warning.

Comment: NP, as for the warning you get, i wrote [an article](https://www.debuggr.io/react-update-unmounted-component/) about it. hope it helps

Comment: btw, i removed the component and it's not throwing that error anymore but i really need that component's abilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is usually thrown when there is an asynchronous operation with a state update involved. By looking at the code you posted it seems there is no async operation that made directly by you, but maybe by a third party library.

It seems like you are using the `react-zoom-pan-pinch` library with the `TransformComponent` which is doing some animations (async operation). By searching through their issues i came a cross some related issues such as [#30](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/issues/30) and [#32](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch/issues/32), it seems to be resolved so you may need to get the latest version. If you still having issues I think its best to open a new issue in their repository.

As for the warning itself, I wrote [an article](https://www.debuggr.io/react-update-unmounted-component/) about it which might help you understand it better.